# Mouse support with ncurses (for python) for large terminals

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, ncurses, tty, python-curses

I'm using python3 with ncurses ([curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html)) inside a docker container. 
The problem is that mouse events are not accurately reporting `x` position in terminals that have more than `222` cells width. At first glance this is an obvious limitation because as far as i can see the position is sent in a single byte.

However [Midnight Commander](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc) accurately handles large terminals. After some digging i could not find how to properly handle mouse with curses (this [example](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2002-April/129986.html) does not work properly). Everything i tried with curses failed to work with large terminals. It seems that midnight commander is using [`gpm`](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/lib/tty/mouse.c), but i could not find any way to use that in python.

q1: How can i handle mouse in large terminals in python3 directly, preferably with curses?

q2: Taking midnight commander as an example, will printing the escape sequences directly in `stdout` make the mouse work as expected ?

q3: Is there any other terminal gui library that handles mouse properly for python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a direct limitation of the python interface to curses, but rather a feature of the underlying curses library, terminal description and the terminal:

- For ncurses, that's the *extended mouse* feature which is standard in ncurses with ABI 6 (available since 2005, standard in [ncurses 6 in 2015](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-6.0.html)), noting that some distributions still provide ABI **5**.
- The terminal description has to use a feature which ncurses recognizes as implying the support for [*SGR 1006*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_277), and of course
- The terminal itself has to support that feature (see note in ncurses database from [January 2018](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t20180121) pointing out a few of the xterm imitators which do ***not***).

Comment: now all of this makes sense, i think the python curses uses and older version of ncurses. Forcing the SGR 1006 escape sequence into stdout does indeed enable extended mouse support in the terminal.